# (Done) Req to reopen what is meant by no tennis shoes in a dress code

Tags: discussion, reopen-request

[What is Generally Meant by "No Tennis Shoes" in a Dress Code](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/162595/what-is-generally-meant-by-no-tennis-shoes-in-a-dress-code)

I believe there's a useful question in here. While we can't say what "No Tennis Shoes" definitively means for a specific company, it is a phrase with general cultural meaning and connotations that can be usefully talked about, such as in this question:

[What is appropriate dress for a "business casual" interview?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/q/1291/31777)

So I've edited the question slightly to make it a general one rather than company-specific and I submit that it should now be reopened.

Comment: Agree, voted to reopen

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As the question had already a couple of reopen votes, and as I also think it should have stayed open, I proceeded to cast a binding vote, and the post is now open again.

I think the post is quite answerable as it already has several answers, many of them highly voted.

The edit Kaz did made it even clearer and on-topic IMO.

Comment: Aaand I just saw the question again in the close queue. I voted leave open but I think too many people are a bit VTC-trigger happy...

Comment: @LP154 post is still open and without VTCs... guess the one you saw expired... but yeah I sensed that some were a bit jumpy to VTC

Comment: yeah there was 2 votes 5 days ago as it's still open I guess they expired but IMO we should do something about this, lots of questions are VTCed and then closed even when they should not be closed. But I don't know what we can do...